# Why is the article omitted before "climate change"?

Tags: articles, zero-article

In the book "Advanced Grammar in Use" there is a sentence:

> We will talk about climate change in a later part of the course.

- Q1: Why is the article completely omitted in front of "climate change"?
- Q2: Would it be wrong to say "We will talk about the climate change in the later part of the course." and so add an article for "climate change" and change the article of "part"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Articles are not generally used with names of phenomena such as *weather, climate, rainfall* when discussing them in a general sense. Of course we say 'What will the weather be like tomorrow?' or 'the climate of Asia', but 'climate change' is a general, worldwide phenomenon.

Answer (score -2):

I would invite other answers as to why "climate change" is zero-marked, other than "the climate change" sounding awkward; but "a later part" is correct, as it is not giving a definitive position (another way of phrasing it is "in another part") of when/where in the course it will be discussed. Replacing indefinite "a" with the definite "the" requires a definitive position, so the phrase would have to change to "the latter part".

Answer (score -2):

Articles originated as demonstratives and there is no demonstrative here.
Page 239 of the book LATIN
And of course, climate is an all-inclusive term that can't be distinguished from non-existent alternate climates.